# How to install new network adapter drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers

I have ubuntu server 18.04.3 and trying to install ixgbe 5.6.3 drivers for my new  X550-10g-T1 network adapter card by navigating into the ixgbe/src folder and running

```
make install
```

I got a bunch of errors that i have no idea what it means

```
below:make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.9-050309-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.o
In file included from /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/kcompat.h:68:0,
                 from /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_osdep.h:17,
                 from /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_type.h:45,
                 from /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_dcb.h:7,
                 from /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe.h:24,
                 from /home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:31:
./include/generated/utsrelease.h:2:32: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
 #define UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI 050309
                                ^
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/kcompat.h:814:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI’
 #if UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI > 255
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/generated/utsrelease.h:2:32: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
 #define UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI 050309
                                ^
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/kcompat.h:812:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI’
         UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI)
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/kcompat.h:5049:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘UBUNTU_VERSION_CODE’
 #if (UBUNTU_VERSION_CODE && UBUNTU_VERSION_CODE >= UBUNTU_VERSION(3,13,0,24))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/generated/utsrelease.h:2:32: error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant
 #define UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI 050309
                                ^
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/kcompat.h:812:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI’
         UTS_UBUNTU_RELEASE_ABI)
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/kcompat.h:5049:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘UBUNTU_VERSION_CODE’
 #if (UBUNTU_VERSION_CODE && UBUNTU_VERSION_CODE >= UBUNTU_VERSION(3,13,0,24))
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:10990:12: warning: ‘struct tc_block_offload’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
     struct tc_block_offload *f)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c: In function ‘ixgbe_setup_tc_block’:
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:10994:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct tc_block_offload’
  if (f->binder_type != TCF_BLOCK_BINDER_TYPE_CLSACT_INGRESS)
       ^~
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:10994:24: error: ‘TCF_BLOCK_BINDER_TYPE_CLSACT_INGRESS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘FLOW_BLOCK_BINDER_TYPE_CLSACT_INGRESS’?
  if (f->binder_type != TCF_BLOCK_BINDER_TYPE_CLSACT_INGRESS)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        FLOW_BLOCK_BINDER_TYPE_CLSACT_INGRESS
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:10994:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:10998:7: error: ‘TC_BLOCK_BIND’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘FLOW_BLOCK_BIND’?
  case TC_BLOCK_BIND:
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
       FLOW_BLOCK_BIND
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:10999:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘tcf_block_cb_register’; did you mean ‘tc_indr_block_cb_register’?  -Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   return tcf_block_cb_register(f->block, ixgbe_setup_tc_block_cb,
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          tc_indr_block_cb_register
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:11005:7: error: ‘TC_BLOCK_UNBIND’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘TC_BLOCK_BIND’?
  case TC_BLOCK_UNBIND:
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       TC_BLOCK_BIND
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:11006:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘tcf_block_cb_unregister’; did you mean ‘tc_indr_block_cb_unregister’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   tcf_block_cb_unregister(f->block, ixgbe_setup_tc_block_cb,
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   tc_indr_block_cb_unregister
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c: At top level:
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:11878:22: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = ixgbe_select_queue,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:11878:22: note: (near initialization for ‘ixgbe_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c: In function ‘ixgbe_setup_tc_block’:
/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.c:11012:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:280: recipe for target '/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src/ixgbe_main.o] Error 1
Makefile:1626: recipe for target '_module_/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/jonathan/ixgbe-5.6.3/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.9-050309-generic'
Makefile:87: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Am following the readMe that told me to grab the tar and un-tar it and go into the src folder and execute make install

My kernel version is 5.3.9

edit: ubuntu clearly sees the new installed NIC but cant use it or install drivers

lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3

```
jonathan@jonney-linux-server:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10G X550T [8086:15d1] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Converged Network Adapter X550-T1 [8086:0002]
        Kernel driver in use: ixgbe
        Kernel modules: ixgbe
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:8505]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Edit : some more logs as requested.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=11r6SOjA1lHObAN28lk9XBHrU2lbKzDa0

sorry i am unable to copy and paste text as i am directly running these commands now locally from the ubuntu server(as i cant connect to the new ethernet adapter via ssh to run it on via my desktop OS machine)

Comment: It looks like the drivers are incompatible with the kernel. Where did you get the drivers. What does readme say about kernel version?

Comment: I got the drivers from here https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/14687/Intel-Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCIe-Intel-10-Gigabit-Ethernet-Network-Connections-Under-Linux-?product=88207

Comment: Does the adapter work without the drivers?

Comment: The driver should build on standard Ubuntu kernels. Also see http://ask.xmodulo.com/download-install-ixgbe-driver-ubuntu-debian.html

Comment: No the adapter doesnt work . You get a green blinking light on the NIC card and on my switch but ubuntu server tells me there is no connection so i assumed i need to install drivers for it. i had to on my windows 10 machine that has the exact same NIC card installed and when i first booted it up it had the same problem as in here and so i installed the drivers on my windows 10 machine.

Comment: It looks like the driver works. You need to configure network intstead of tinkering with drivers. Most likely interface name has changed. How did you configured network? Linux systems don't require external drivers in most cases unlike Windows.

Comment: @jonney please [edit] your post with the output of `ip l`

Comment: Your adapter already has the required driver, *ixgbe*. I suspect that the netplan file is faulty. Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `ip addr show`

Comment: Ok i will post the output of that in a biit

Comment: I have just posted the results of executing ip l, cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml and ip addr show on a screenshot of it

Answer (score 1):

Ahh i got it to work!

i added this to the netplan and i also removed the previous "assigned static ip" that was on my old network device and it worked

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      enp0s3:
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp6: yes
```